# Php-Reports Stripe Building

Tags: php, stripe-payments

First question on here as an enthusiast trying to get this to work.

Using the open source project by jdorn [PHP-Reports](http://jdorn.github.io/php-reports/) and following the stripe custom reporting tutorials.

The report never returns, what I am trying to achieve is custom Stripe payments reporting using the Stripe API to return all charges, to then display in a nice table

Here is my paymentreport.php code

```
<?php
//My Payments Report
//This connects to the Stripe Payments api and shows a list of charges
//VARIABLE: { name: "count", display: "Number of Charges" }


// Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('StripeTestCodeAPIKEY');

if($count > 100 || $count < 1) throw new Exception("Number of Charges must be between 1 and 100");


// Retrieve a list of 50 most recent charges
$charges = \Stripe\Charge::all(array(
             'limit' => 50
           ));

// Loop through each charge
foreach ($charges->data as $charge) {

    // Get the required charge information and assign to variables
    $id = $charge->id;
    $description = $charge->description;
    $created = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i', $charge->created); // Format the time
    $amount = $charge->amount/100; // Convert amount from cents to dollars
    $currency = $charge->currency;

$rows = array();
foreach($charges as $charge) {
    $rows[] = array(
        'Charge Id'=>$charge->id,
        'Amount'=>number_format($charge->amount/100,2),
        'Date'=>date('Y-m-d',$charge->created)
    );
}

echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems here-- you accept a `$count`-variable that's never used.  I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
$charges = \Stripe\Charge::all(array(
  'limit' => $count
));
```

Additionally, you've got a loop at the bottom that's broken.  You've got to remove the second `foreach` and move the `$rows = array();` outside of the first loop.

Finally, the last call `$rows[] = array(...)` should probably also include the variables you captured above.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you, yes it makes sense, however, the $count variable is taking input from a user beforehand specified in the header `//VARIABLE: { name: "count", display: "Number of Charges" }` so would that still require a change?